# How is the process of making the bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I have a JabRef database in the same folder as my *.tex directory. Im using the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
 \usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{biblatex}
 \bibliography{Biblio}

\begin{document}
JUNasdladadljkasljkds \cite{someauthor}

\end{document}
```

But nothing happends

Comment: Possible duplicate: [`biblatex` for idiots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/5764)

Comment: See also [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for which programmes to run on your file (you will need to run Biber or BibTeX as well) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `\printbibliography` before `\end{document}` in order to get the bibliography to show up.

After compiling this with either `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, or `laulatex`. You need to run `biber` and then the LaTeX engine from the previous sentence in order to have the bibliography database properly read, sorted, and formatted.

Another note `\bibliography` is deprecated in `biblatex`. Use `\addbibresource` instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
JUNasdladadljkasljkds \cite{someauthor}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add the explanaition for using `pdflatex`, `biber` or `bibtex` (missing backend option for biblatex), `pdflatex`, `pdflatex` and that biber/bibtex creates a bbl file, log in blg file.  Then I will upvote your answer.

Comment: Please note that while the MWE might not give the output one might wish for, still it *does* work, it just doesn't display a bibliography since - as you noted - the `\printbibliography` is missing. It is not per se necessary to have a `\printbibliography`. Also `\addbibresource` needs the file extension, so it should be `\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}`. On my MikTeX system `\addbibresource{Biblio}` without the `.bib` does not work.